# Ionic build failed on Ionic Pro

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I got an issue building with Ionic pro

it return

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-ionic': CordovaError: Version of
>   installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@5.0.1" does not satisfy
>   dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@^4.0.0".
>   Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency

Why that? my `cordova-plugin-splashscreen@^4.0.0` is already above required version?

Comment: Did you fix that? I have the same problem, which caused me can not run `ionic cordova build browser --aot --prod`